# Interactive visualization of millions (>5M) of rectangles

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface, large-data

[image]I have a dataset with placement (X/Y) information of millions of rectangles along with their widths and heights. There could be additional properties associated with each of the rectangles which I will need to display as color map or tooltip on hover, but I can add support for that later. Typical format for the data would look something like below but I can pre-process it to make it conducive to the solutions suggested.

```
# #rect_label x y width height  rect_type<br>
rect_0      1.23 3.45 0.62 0.45   and_gate<br>
rect_1      2.67 0.23 0.75 1.20   or_gate<br>
....
```

I want to display the placement of these rectangles preferably in a web browser (with python backend) or if not, in a stand-alone python based GUI, with ability to zoom/pan and select the rectangles.

I have tried the scatter plots in plotly and bokeh but the bowser just dies with the amount of data I am trying to plot. I chose those two packages primarily because I needed interactivity.

I am a novice when it comes to data visualization. Would appreciate any help. Below image kind of shows what I am trying to mimic.

Comment: There's no image at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Instead of rendering all the rectangles, you could look at solutions where you query the back end for data local to the pointer or other interactive elements of your interface. Another approach would be to group elements together at zoom levels where they can't even be individually rendered, similar to what libraries like OpenLayers will let you do.

Considering your question is more about interactive web interfaces than python per se, I'd also suggest labelling your question `javascript` in addition to `python` and it doesn't have a lot to do with `big data`.